# Jest gives an error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token export using Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, angular, jestjs, google-tag-manager, ts-jest

I'm using Jest to test my Angular App.
Recently, I added Angular Google Tag Manager to my app, my tests fail with this error:

```
my-project/node_modules/angular-google-tag-manager/angular-google-tag-manager.d.ts:5
export \* from './public-api';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

15 | import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
16 | import { NavigationEnd, Router, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';
17 | import { GoogleTagManagerService } from 'angular-google-tag-manager';
     ^
18 | import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
19 | import { AuthenticationService } from '../auth/authentication/authentication.service';
20 | import { ChatBotService } from '../chat-bot/chat-bot.service';
```

at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../../../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
at Object.<anonymous> (../../core/src/lib/header/header.component.ts:17:1)

This looks like an issue with Jest transforming a node module before running it's tests.

Here is my jest setup:

```
module.exports = {
  displayName: 'my-project',
  preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts', 'jest-canvas-mock'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['../../../node_modules/(?!variables/.*)'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
      astTransformers: {
        before: [
          'jest-preset-angular/build/InlineFilesTransformer',
          'jest-preset-angular/build/StripStylesTransformer',
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/my-project',
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment',
  ],
  coverageReporters: ['lcov', 'json'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    'public-api': '<rootDir>/node_modules/angular-google-tag-manager/esm2020/public-api.d.ts',
  },
};
```

I seem to have the correct things necessary to transform export * from 'public-api'. So any ideas whats going wrong?

Comment: If you remove `transformIgnorePatterns` line from your jest config, does it work?